# How to fix 'shift/reduce' conflict in bison grammar for C preprocessor?

Tags: parsing, bison

I am writing a scanner/parser for a C preprocessor.
I've just been copying the grammar directly from [this specification, Annex A](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

I've run into a shift/reduce error. While I understand what this means in theory, devising a solution still eludes me.

You can view both the grammar and the resulting output file [at this gist](https://gist.github.com/JustAPerson/5f0d6bf80c461b9b8d5fa31e4c90df91).

Can anyone help?
I know you can resolve a shift/reduce with precedence/associativity specifiers, but I'm uncertain what exactly to do.

Edit: I recognize many people ask similar questions, but it's quite hard to apply answers from someone else's grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem you have here is that you have `#` as a separate token from the keyword of a directive, so you need two-token lookahead to determine which preprocessor directive comes next.  Bison only uses one token lookahead, so you get conflicts on pretty much every preprocessor directive.

The easiest way to fix this is to have your lexer recognize the entire preprocessor directive as a single token (eg `"#"[ \t]*if  { return IF; }` if you're using lex) rather than as two tokens.